# I need help installing FFMPEG on my server

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, mp3

I'm trying to get FFMPEG installed on my VPS.

Plesk Obsidian Version 18.0.59
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Basically, I need FFMPEG installed, as the custom MP3 player I use for my website can generate audio previews, but needs FFMPeg installed on my server to do so. A friend of mine is helping me with the management of the server, but we can't seem to get the audio previews as an option. We have contacted IONOS (who I bought the VPS off) and Sonaar (who make the MP3 player), and they say FFMPEG may not be installed correctly. As it's a self managed server, my support with IONOS is very limited.

The steps we have done so far are:

01: Installed FFMPeg on the server. It says to change the path in the MP3 player settings, to reflect the installation path, which we did (/usr/bin/ffmpeg).

02: Once FFMPeg was installed on the server, we made sure the server allowed shell_exec() function, and changed the "Raise max_execution_time" and "max_input_time to 900" as per the instructions from Sonaar.

03: Installed the PHP wrapper for FFMPeg.

But we still don't have the option to add audio previews on the MP3 player, and the developers are adamant that it must be a problem with either the installation, or we may need to do something else, as we are using Plex Obsidian, but myself and my friend are out of ideas.

Apologies if this post is a bit vague guys, but any help would be greatly appreciated.